Understanding ～ところだった for expressing something almost happened as counterfactuals?
It is odd to me that this ～ところだった is often treated as a separate grammar point than the ～ところだ learned in JLPT N4 grammar and I want to understand why. I think this can be understood if one thinks ～ところだった as ～たら～ところだった.
As an example, consider this sentence:

本を読んでいるところだった。

This sentence is ambiguous. It either means "I was reading a book" or "I was almost about to read a book." I had a hard time understanding how it is possible to get to the second meaning. I then had an epiphany: I believe that if one can rewrite the sentence to something like

友達から電話が来なかったら、本を読んでいるところだった。
If my friend didn't call me (at that time), then I would be reading a book.

(The bold part depends on context.)
Then it makes sense to say "I was almost about to read a book."
Another example, here is one of the example sentence taken from the linked website:

イタズラしすぎたせいで、もう少しで彼を怒らせるところでした。

I think it can be rewritten to something like as

イタズラしすぎたせいで、もう少しでイタズラしていれば彼を怒らせるところでした。

So, if my theory is correct, I don't see how this ～ところだった is different from the ordinary ～ところだ learned in JLPT N4 grammar.

This sentence is ambiguous. It either means "I was reading a book" or "I was almost about to read a book." Is that really true?

You need to consider the difference between 読んでいる and 読む.  If you understand that difference, you should be able to understand how 読んでいるところ and 読むところ differ.  If you think they can mean the same thing, you're not understanding the difference in the verb forms.

I got an impression that ところだった sometimes can be used to express hypothetical situations.

The page you linked says that it is talking about 〜ところだった where the 〜 is a verb in dictionary form or ない form. I take it that they would have listed ている form if they meant for the explanation to apply to that.

I think there are a couple questions here.

Are 〜ところだ　and ~ところだった grammatically different concepts? If so, why?

These are not separate. I think the reason the JLPT introduces them separately is because of the use of the past with hypothetical statements. But this is more of a conceptual, rather than a grammatical, issue.
For instance:
本を読むところだった。　I was about to read a book.
本を読むところだ。　　　I'm about to read a book.
These are literally, in both Japanese and English, only different in terms of time. But if you change the time to the past you are suggesting that it might not have happened. This is not necessarily the case though. You could have read the book. For instance,
Q: いつ配達が届きましたか？
A: 本を読むところだった。
There is nothing in this that suggests that they did not go back and finish reading the book after getting the delivery.
However, the grammatical examples in JLPT N2 are all hypotheticals - "If 'A' happened (or didn't happen) then 'B' was about to happen." The present form could be viewed as a hypothetical as well. "I'm about to watch TV." But that might not actually happen. It's a proposed future activity, even if the future is very close.

Can 本を読んでいるところだった。 be translated as "I was almost about to read a book."?

This is not a correct translation of the sentence. As some others have noted, 〜ているところだった means the speaker was in the middle of something in the past. It does not mean they were about to do something. Similarly "past tense" + ところだった means the speaker had just finished something in the past. For instance,
飯を食ったところだった。　I had just finished eating.
Nothing hypothetical here. The only place a hypothetical is possible is when using  "dictionary form" + ところだった。

I did some research and I found some examples for hypothetical use of 〜ているところだった. Like this for example. So it seems like 〜ところだ can be used for both factual (not sure if it is the right term) and hypothetical situations...

It may be possible in this kind of edge case, where the verb being used is more abstract, but in the majority of cases, for instance when using a verb like 読む it is not used that way.

Your use of "hypothetical" seems a bit strange to me.  Speaking of hypothetical makes it sound like a conditional statement which may or may not have been true at the time of speaking.  But saying something like 読むところだ, there's nothing hypothetical, you're describing the situation as it was: "I am about to read".  Either you were or you weren't.  But, if you weren't, then you would being lying.  If it were truly hypothetical, then this would not be a lie.
